# choose a position on printed wire, java string

Tags: java, string, println

I am attempting to have my program print(command window) this> "----------" in any length from 1 - 100:

```
public void display()
   {
       for (int x=0; x < Length; x++)
       {
           System.out.print("-");
       }
   }
```

However, I need a "bug" to land somewhere on this wire: for example: ----0---- and be able to remember that position and move along the wire. I am not asking for the answer to solve this but help on what keywords to lookup and reading on something like this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Be careful when you ask for a "bug" to land on your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I need a "bug" to land somewhere on this wire

You can use `Random` as follows:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(100);

    char[] chr = new char[100];
    Arrays.fill(chr,'-');
    chr[randomNumber] = '0';

    System.out.print(new String(chr));
}
```

Here, `randomNumber` will hold the position of the bug for you.

Comment: Or better, fill everything with "-" and finally replace a random place with a "0".

Comment: @MarounMaroun I like that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that is by calling method with argument that specifies position of the bug. That way you know position of the bug.

```
public void display(int position)
   {
       for (int x=0; x < Length; x++)
       {
            if (x == position) {
                System.out.print("O");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
       }
   }
```